# How to show an alert msg in react native when we have failed api response

Tags: react-native, alert

I am not able to get an alert when the api response fails.I am trying to add the alert in where the actions are getting dispatched.Can we trigger an alert of we have redirect to a different page after the submission? Is there any other way to show the error msg when the api response fails.

```
const saveOPPInfo = () => {
      this.setState({
        _firstNameEmpty: isEmpty(_firstName),
        _lastNameEmpty: isEmpty(_lastName),
        _emailNotValid: !validateEmail(_email)
      });
      if (
        this.isSaveAttempted ||
        isEmpty(_firstName) ||
        isEmpty(_lastName) ||
        !validateEmail(_email)
      ) {
        return;
      }
      this.isSaveAttempted = true;
      this.setState({ _isFetching: true });
      if (action === "ADD") {
        const jsonPayload = [
          {
            email: _email,
            firstName: _firstName,
            lastName: _lastName,
            isPrimary: false
          }
        ];
        addOtherPickupPerson({ purchaseContractId, jsonPayload }).then(() => {
          GroceryNotifierApi.events().emitOnAction("saveOPPInfo", "");
        });
      } else {
        const jsonPayload = {
          email: _email,
          firstName: _firstName,
          lastName: _lastName,
          isPrimary: false
        };
        editOtherPickupPerson({ purchaseContractId, jsonPayload, pickupPersonId: _id }).then(() => {
          GroceryNotifierApi.events().emitOnAction("saveOPPInfo", "");
        });
      }
    };
```

here is the part of jsx

```
<View
          style={{
            paddingLeft: 20,
            paddingRight: 20,
            paddingTop: 24
          }}
        >
          {action === "ADD" ? (
            <Body>
              {OPP_ADD_OPP_DESC}
              <Body
                onPress={() => nativeNav.navigateToOPPLearnMore()}
                style={{ textDecorationLine: "underline" }}
              >
                {OPP_LEARN_MORE}
              </Body>
            </Body>
          ) : (
            <View />
          )}
        </View>
        {_isFetching && (
          <View style={{ height: 120 }}>
            <CircularIndicator />
          </View>
        )}
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <PrimaryButton
            style={styles.saveButton}
            testID="save"
            block
            onPress={saveOPPInfo}
            disabled={this.isSaveAttempted || _firstNameEmpty || _lastNameEmpty || _emailNotValid}
          >
            {isIOS ? "Save" : "SAVE"}
          </PrimaryButton>
          {action === "ADD" ? (
            <View />
          ) : (
            <LinkButton onPress={removeOPPInfo} disabled={this.isSaveAttempted}>
              {OPP_REMOVE}
            </LinkButton>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

this is how the action looks

```
export const addOtherPickupPersonRequest = createAction(ADD_OTHER_PICKUP_PERSON_REQUEST);
export const addOtherPickupPersonSuccess = createAction(ADD_OTHER_PICKUP_PERSON_SUCCESS);
export const addOtherPickupPersonFail = createAction(ADD_OTHER_PICKUP_PERSON_FAIL);

export const addOtherPickupPerson = ({ purchaseContractId, jsonPayload }) => {
  return async function(dispatch) {
   store.dispatch(addOtherPickupPersonRequest());
    let response;
    let responseJson;
    try {
      const startTime = new Date().getTime();
      response = await fetchAddOtherPickupPerson(purchaseContractId, jsonPayload);
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        trackPerformance("checkout-add-opp-api", startTime, "performance-metric");
        responseJson = await response.json();

        store.dispatch(addOtherPickupPersonSuccess(responseJson));
        return responseJson;
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          "Oops22!",
          "Something is not working here. Please check back later.",
          [{ text: "Okay" }],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
        await Promise.reject(err);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      trackErrorEvent("checkout-add-opp-api", { ...defaultPayload({ err }) }, "api-error");
      Alert.alert(
        "Oops!",
        "Something is not working here. Please check back later.",
        [{ text: "Okay" }],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      return store.dispatch(addOtherPickupPersonFail(err));
    }
  };
};
```

I want to show an alert when the response.status is not `response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)`

Comment: Do you import Alert from react-native?

Comment: yes imported alert from react-native

Comment: Maybe try and manage status inside a .then() statement instead of managing it outside?